# How to determine whether object reference is null?

Tags: c#, object, null, visual-studio-2005, object-reference

What is the best way to determine whether an object reference variable is `null`?

Is it the following?

```
MyObject myObjVar = null;
if (myObjVar == null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: If you want to default to something, you can always do `MyObject obj = myObjVar ?? DefaultObjVar`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the following snippet is the way to go if you want to execute arbitrary code:

```
MyObject myObjVar; 
if (myObjVar == null) 
{ 
    // do stuff 
}
```

BTW: Your code wouldn't compile the way it is now, because `myObjVar` is accessed before it is being initialized.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Object.ReferenceEquals

```
if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, myObjVar)) 
{
   ....... 
}
```

This would return true, if the myObjVar is null.

Comment: This is useful if you want to override the == operator for an object.

Comment: If you happen to be wanting to test for null *inside* your implementation of `==` then I think `Object.ReferenceEquals` is essential.

Answer (score 7):

The way you are doing is the best way

```
if (myObjVar == null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

but  you can use [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) `??` to check, as well as **assign something**

```
var obj  = myObjVar ?? new MyObject();
```

Comment: I think that the null-coalescing operator was introduced in C# 2

Answer (score 3):

you can:

```
MyObject myObjVar = MethodThatMayOrMayNotReturnNull();
if (if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, myObjVar)) 
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: why the need for two if statements?

Answer (score 0):

In `C# 7.0` you can use `is null`:

```
MyObject myObjVar = null;
if (myObjVar is null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```