# How to handle null dates value using object

Tags: c#, asp.net

How handle null value using object in C# ASP.NET C#.

Below I am doing visible true and false base on condition using hyperlink.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"  Text="Date not confirm" 
     Visible='<%#GetVisible2(Eval("DateofEvent").ToString()=="")%>'></asp:Label>
```

below is my c# code.

```
public bool GetVisible2(object value)
{
    if (value=="")
    {
        //return value.ToString() == "Visible";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Every time returning false only. I dont know if condition is correct or wrong.

Comment: try searching in Google --  https://www.google.co.in/search?q=C%23+null+value+check&oq=C%23+null+value+check&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.4608j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I searched thats why came here for help, please help. @KarthikAMR

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000228/how-to-determine-whether-object-reference-is-null
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417902/checking-if-an-object-is-null-in-c-sharp

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger. Then set a breakpoint in the method and check the type and value ob the passed value.

Answer (score 0):

By default DateTime variable takes DateTime.MinValue so you should compare it with this as below:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"  Text="Date not confirm" 
         Visible='<%#GetVisible2(Eval("DateofEvent"))%>'></asp:Label>

    public bool GetVisible2(DateTime? value)
    {
        if (value == null || value == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: what if the return value is `null`

Comment: Okay.. Then you need to use ? with DataTime like this: DateTime? value in function parameter. I will update in post

Answer (score 0):

Because you passing your function a boolean value which never equals to empty string:

```
Eval("DateofEvent").ToString()=="" // this will generate true or false
```

this will pass boolean to GetVisible2. Try this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"  Text="Date not confirm" 
     Visible='<%#GetVisible2(Eval("DateofEvent").ToString())%>'></asp:Label>
```

and you can change function as:

```
public bool GetVisible2(string value)
{
   return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
}
```

or much cleaner approach as suggested by Tim Schmelter, without any validation method:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"  Text="Date not confirm" 
     Visible='<%#String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DateofEvent").ToStrin‌​g())%>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: getting this error: Argument 1: cannot convert from object to string. @Zaheer Ahmed

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: fine, but now this begs the question why he needs the method at all. `Visible='<%#String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DateofEvent").ToString())%>'`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I wanted to suggest but right now I wasn't able to confirm the syntax. So thanks for putting it here :)

Answer (score 0):

You are evaluating a function inside ASPX page and passing a Boolean value to your GetVisible2 function.

This is why you are returning false everytime, since the object value is never a string, but a boolean.

Should be

```
Eval("DateofEvent")
```

insteadof

```
Eval("DateofEvent").ToString() == ""
```

And the function will be

```
public bool GetVisible2(object value)
{
    return value!=null;
}
```

Or, if you want to consider empty strings "null" also, you can do the following

```
public bool GetVisible2(object value)
{
    var s = value as string;
    return value!=null || (s is string && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string));
}
```

> gettting error: object doest not contain a definiation for to string and no extension method tostring acception a first argument of type object could be found. @OrcusZ

It's not

```
toString()
```

but it's

```
ToString()
```

C# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to pass the `DateofEvent` before converting it to string, because; if `DateofEvent` is null then the `.ToString()` will raise `NullReference`, So the changes would be like the following:

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"  Text="Date not confirm" 
 Visible='<%#IsVisible(Eval("DateofEvent"))%>'></asp:Label>
```

So the parameter passed to the method will be an object, we have to check for null and then for Empty string, So the method will be like this:

```
public bool IsVisible(object value)
{
   return value != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString());
}
```

Or even something like this: `return value != null && value.ToString()!="";`

Comment: I think there is no need to use object as a parameter, your value will always be either null or a datetime so you should use DateTime? which can accept both null and datetime. Please check my answer also

Answer (score -1):

A method exist to check is a string is null :

```
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: gettting error: object doest not contain a definiation for to string and no extension method tostring acception a first argument of type object could be found. @OrcusZ

Comment: if `value` is `null` then `.ToString()` will give you NullReferenceException`

Comment: `IsNullOrEmpty` is a static method in the string class, so you have to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString())`. But that doesn't help OP, because   if this would work OP's code would also work.

Comment: Your right, sorry is the morning in France, I need to take a coffe to wake up ^^

Comment: @OrcusZ: well, it's still not compiling because `value` is an object but `IsNullOrEmpty` takes a `string`. Also, you have to check if `value` is null otherwise you might get a `NullReferenceException` at `value.ToString`. Finally, this is the same as OP's `== ""`-check. But OP compares the return value of the method with `==""` which cannot work because the method returns a bool.

Comment: if value is null, is still getting the issue, he should change the input param to string. if he need to stay with object he can just check if the object is null